# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/forums/comments")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I use `inherited_resources 1.5.0 gem` and `angularjs` in my new rails project. I have 2 model: `forum` and `comment`. I create all form with `angularjs` and get data from user and post to rails server to create new method. For forum, it's ok, but when I want add comment to forums (`has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy`), I get below error in `server log`:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/forums/comments")
```

when I run `rake routes` I see below routing:

```
    forum_comments GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index {:format=>:json}
                   POST   /forums/:forum_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create {:format=>:json}
 new_forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new {:format=>:json}
edit_forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit {:format=>:json}
     forum_comment GET    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show {:format=>:json}
                   PATCH  /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update {:format=>:json}
                   PUT    /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update {:format=>:json}
                   DELETE /forums/:forum_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy {:format=>:json}
            forums GET    /forums(.:format)                             forums#index {:format=>:json}
                   POST   /forums(.:format)                             forums#create {:format=>:json}
         new_forum GET    /forums/new(.:format)                         forums#new {:format=>:json}
        edit_forum GET    /forums/:id/edit(.:format)                    forums#edit {:format=>:json}
             forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#show {:format=>:json}
                   PATCH  /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#update {:format=>:json}
                   PUT    /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#update {:format=>:json}
                   DELETE /forums/:id(.:format)                         forums#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

`forums_controller.rb`:

```
class ForumsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json

  def forum_params
    params.require(:forum).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

`forum.rb`:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

`comments_controller`:

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  respond_to :json

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:forum_id, :name, :body)
  end
end
```

`comment.rb`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
end
```

and I have below code in angularjs:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('CommentsController', ['$scope', 'Comment', '$routeParams', function($scope, Comment, $routeParams) {
    //Grab all the comments from the server
    $scope.comments = Comment.query({forum_id: $routeParams.id});

    //Define a 'save' method which will be called from the view.
    $scope.save = function() {
        //Create the comment object to be sent to the server
        var obj = new Comment({name: $scope.name, body: $scope.body, forum_id: $routeParams.id});

        //Attempt a save to the back-end
        obj.$save(function(response) {

            //If we're successful then add the response (the object as the server sees it)
            // to our collection of comments
            $scope.comments.unshift(response);

            //Empty the name & body
            $scope.name = $scope.body = ""

        }, function(response) {

            //If there's a failure set the 'errors' scope variable so it'll be reflected in the view.
            $scope.errors = response.data.errors;
        });
    }
}]);
```

And when I post data, I get bwlow error in chrome console too:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/forums/comments?forum_id=7 404 (Not Found) angular.min.js?body=1:81
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:81
t angular.min.js?body=1:76
f angular.min.js?body=1:74
I angular.min.js?body=1:102
I angular.min.js?body=1:102
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:103
h.$eval angular.min.js?body=1:114
h.$digest angular.min.js?body=1:111
h.$apply angular.min.js?body=1:115
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:203
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4642
elemData.handle jquery.js?body=1:4310
```

How can I fix this problem and set route to `/forums/comments`?

Comment: Angular JS is POSTing to `/forums/comments?forum_id=7`. But routes defined in rails is  `/forums/:forum_id/comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post comments to wrong url. I have a `model.js` in my angularjs code and I set the url in this js file. I correction the code like below:

`angular/model.js`:

```
'use strict';    
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.factory('Comment', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/forums/:forum_id/comments/:id', {forum_id: '@forum_id', id: '@id'});
    }]);
```

Now angularjs POST data to `/forums/:forum_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create {:format=>:json}` and rails permit to add data to database.